# Login without role

Tags: c#, sql-server, authentication

I have a made a cashier system with two roles such as admin and cashier. I need to update my application where I want to get rid of the role, and when the user enter the username and password the form want to be loaded according to their roles. In other words  I don't want the user to selected the role from the login.

I'm using Visual Studio 15 and Microsoft SQL server 14. Below code is the button to login.

[image: Login Page]

```
Form2 dash = new Form2();
    Form10 userdash = new Form10();
    DBConnection.DBC_Connection db = new DBConnection.DBC_Connection();
    DBConnection.Login lg = new DBConnection.Login();

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select count(*) from Login where Type='" + comboBox1Type.Text + "' and Username='" + textBox1.Text + "'and Password='" + textBox2.Text + "'", db.creatconnection());
    DataTable dta = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dta);
    if (dta.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1" && comboBox1Type.Text == "Admin")
    {
        this.Hide();
        dash.Show();
    }

    else
    {
        if (dta.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1" && comboBox1Type.Text == "User")
        {
            this.Hide();
            userdash.Show();
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Login try checking Useraname Or Password !" , "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the Type based on the credentials and then check the returned Type of user.

```
    Form2 dash = new Form2();
    Form10 userdash = new Form10();
    DBConnection.DBC_Connection db = new DBConnection.DBC_Connection();
    DBConnection.Login lg = new DBConnection.Login();

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Login where Username='" + textBox1.Text + "'and Password='" + textBox2.Text + "'", db.creatconnection());
    DataTable dta = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dta);

    if(dta.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        if(dta.Rows[0]["Type"].ToString() == "Admin")
        {
            this.Hide();
            dash.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            this.Hide();
            userdash.Show();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Login try checking Useraname Or Password !" , "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
```

In the select statement * will return Type as well. So if DataTable has any row then user is authenticated. Now check what kind of role does this user has by checking the Type field in the DataTable.

Comment: Thanks alot i tried your changes works well thanks alot for your valuable code

Answer (score 0):

You can use an additional column in the Users Table to check for Roles

```
Create table users (
username varchar2(50) not null,
password varchar2(50) not null,
role char not null, // this takes either 0 or 1 (admin , user)
constraints PK_USERS PRIMARY KEY (username)
)
```

**Concerning your c# code** : you can do a function hide & shows the necessary controls for each role.

If you have multiple forms you can save the **Role** fetched in a static variable and do the work.